# how to connection of audio jack of headphone

Tags: audio

My headphone jack has broken. There are 3 wires green, blue and red with green strip...
Which one will be the ground wire and which one will be speaker wire.(left & right).??
And how to test it with multimeter??

Answer (score 3):

Use ohms on your multimeter and put your headphones on as a double check.

The multimeter will inject a mA or so into the headphone speakers and this can be heard so also turn the TV off because it won't be amazingly loud.

Select two of the wires out of the three and touch your multimeter probes across the bare ends of the wires. You will hear: -

- A sound from the left speaker
- A sound from the right speaker
- A sound from both speakers

Select the two wires that give you a sound from both speakers.

The wire not selected is ground.

Then use the ground wire and another wire to determine if it is left or right.